# How to make my user input become a heading on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onchange

I'm attempting to accomplish something like this. I want my user input to display as a heading in my webpage and I want it to change as my user is typing it. Is it possible to be done without a button? Thanks.

```
<body>
<input type ="text" id="name" onchange="document.getElementById('username') = this.value">
<br>
<h3 id="username"> </h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want can be accomplished with `innerHTML` and `onkeyup`, like so:

```
<body>
     <input type ="text" id="name" onkeyup="document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = this.value;" />
     <br />
     <h3 id="username"> </h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help :)

Comment: @MikeTaylor Ever get enough rep? **He asks 5 years later** XD

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
<input type ="text" id="name" onchange="document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = this.value">
<br>
<h3 id="username"> </h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest you to use the `onkeyup` event rather than the `onchange` event. So you will need this function...

```
function setHeader(){
    var value = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = value; 
}
```

Then change the input to....

```
<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="setHeader()" />
```